# How do I send an object to an awaiting function on a sister screen in a RootStack setup with React Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I've looked high and low, but I can't seem to find an answer. I'm working on an app that is gathering a lot of info and creating an object based on the user's answers.

Here is my setup in App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import {
  createAppContainer,
  StackActions,
  NavigationActions,
  createSwitchNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation'; // Version can be specified in package.json
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
....

const check = false;

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({
 DashboardScreen: {
    screen: Dashboard,
  },
  Workflow: {
    screen: Workflow,
    headerRight: () => (
      <Icon
        containerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 20 }}
        name={unsubscribe() ? 'unlink' : 'link'}
        type="font-awesome"
        size={20}
        color={unsubscribe() ? common.colors.success : common.colors.error}
      />
    ),
  },


RequestsScreen: {
    screen: Requests,
    headerRight: () => (
      <Icon
        containerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 20 }}
        name={unsubscribe() ? 'unlink' : 'link'}
        type="font-awesome"
        size={20}
        color={unsubscribe() ? common.colors.success : common.colors.error}
      />
    ),
  },
  SubmitScreen: {
    screen: Submit,
    headerRight: () => (
      <Icon
        containerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 20 }}
        name={unsubscribe() ? 'unlink' : 'link'}
        type="font-awesome"
        size={20}
        color={unsubscribe() ? common.colors.success : common.colors.error}
      />
    ),
  },
  Photos: {
    screen: PhotosScreen,
    headerRight: () => (
      <Icon
        containerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 20 }}
        name={unsubscribe() ? 'unlink' : 'link'}
        type="font-awesome"
        size={20}
        color={unsubscribe() ? common.colors.success : common.colors.error}
      />
    ),
  },
 NotesScreen: {
    screen: Notes,
    headerRight: () => (
      <Icon
        containerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 20 }}
        name={unsubscribe() ? 'unlink' : 'link'}
        type="font-awesome"
        size={20}
        color={unsubscribe() ? common.colors.success : common.colors.error}
      />
    ),
  };

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false,
    },
  },
  Login: {
    screen: LoginScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false,
    },
  },
  transitionConfig: () => fromRight(),
});

class ModalScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      sample: '',
    };
  }

  textFunc = (text) => {
    Alert.alert(text);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>{this.state.sample}</Text>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>This is a modal!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: AppStack,
    },
    MyModal: {
      screen: ModalScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
      App: AppContainer,
      Auth: AuthStack,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
    }
  )
);
```

The user is finalizing the object on SubmitScreen and needs to send that object to the MyModal screen. I don't really care if this screen is a modal or not. It will be hidden  since it needs to render Views and generate PDFs from those views in the background. I want the user to stay on the SubmitScreen until the process is completed to show a success or error message.

How would I accomplish this goal? Small caveat: we're not ready to upgrade to React Navigation v5 yet. We're running v4.

Comment: Are you using `navigation.goback()` after success or error?

Comment: Are you navigating on after success or error on `MyModal` screen or coming back or this `MyModal` screen? with `navigation.goback()`?

Comment: Sorry, that was just copy and paste from their docs. I wanted to see if I could indeed pull the modal up from another screen, which I could. But that' won't be apart of the actual workflow. So if it helps you can ignore that. I'll edit my code as such.

Comment: As per my understanding, This question is becomes useless now?